# Efficient subsetting of pandas dataframe with indexes in 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a 2d (in future it may be a 3d) array with indicies. Let's say it looks like that:

```
[[1,1,1],
[1,2,2],
[2,2,3]]
```

And I have a pandas dataframe:

```
index, A, B
1, 0.1, 0.01
2, 0.2, 0.02
3, 0,3, 0.03
```

I want to get a numpy array (or pandas df) with values from column A, sliced based on numpy array. So the result would be here:

```
[[0.1,0.1,0.1],
[0.1,0.2,0.2],
[0.2,0.2,0.3]]
```

I can do it with a loop to get pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.A[val].values for val in array)
```

However I'm looking for more efficient way to do it. Is there better way that allows me to use whole array of indices at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.loc[a.ravel(),'A'].values.reshape(a.shape)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.3]])
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!